# Python: Using JSON API link to display named capture group through regex

Tags: python, json, regex-group

I am having trouble displaying the right named capture group by using regex. I already have the regex formula it to capture that group. Here is my [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jt0Aq8/2) link to show. By looking at the link, I am trying to display the text highlighted in green.

The green part is the page titles from the link-contained JSON API. They are labeled as 'article.' What I've done so far is to parse through the JSON to get the list of articles and display it. Some articles have multiple pages and I am just trying to display that very first page. That is why I used REGEX since I am working with huge files here. I am trying to get that green part of the regex to display within my function. This is the [link](https://repl.it/@smokingpenguin/BigheartedSecretDegree) of where my working code without regex implementation. Here is what I tried my code so far:

```
import json
import requests
import re

link = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikiversity/all-access/2018/01/10"

def making_data(link):
  response = requests.get(link, [])
  data = response.json()
  json_data = data['items']
  articles_list = []

  whole_re= re.compile(r'^[^\/].*')
  rx = re.compile(r'(^[^\/]+)')
  for items in json_data:
      articles = items['articles']
      #Iterate over the list of articles
      for article in articles:
          m = whole_re.match(article)
          if m: 
            articles_list.append(m)
            articles = article.get("article")
            search_match = rx.match(article)
            if search_match: 
              print("Page: %s" % articles)

  return sorted(articles_list)

making_data(link)
```

I keep getting an error with regex. I think I am implementing this wrong with JSON and regex.

I want the output to just display what is highlighted in green from the regex link provided and not the following text after that.

```
Page: Psycholinguistics
Page: Java_Tutorial
Page: United_States_currency
```

I hope this all makes sense. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @GiraffeMan91I keep getting this on repl: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Added an answer. You should consider you are going to be dropping subsequent pages after the first unless you loop through your options there using something like `.findall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print your `article` you will see it is a dictionary format.  Your regex isn't what is wrong here, instead it is how you are referencing `article`.

You intend to reference `article_title = article.get("article")` from your original code that you linked, I believe.

Another thing that will become an issue is renaming `articles` in the middle of your loop.  I made some edits for you to get you going but it will need some refinement based on your exact usage and results that you want.

You can reference a match object group with `.group(1)`

```py
import json
import requests
import re

link = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikiversity/all-access/2018/01/10"

def making_data(link):
  response = requests.get(link, [])
  data = response.json()
  json_data = data['items']
  articles_list = []

  whole_re= re.compile(r'^[^\/].*')
  rx = re.compile(r'(^[^\/]+)')
  for items in json_data:
      articles = items['articles']
      #Iterate over the list of articles
      for article in articles:          
          article_title = article.get("article")
          m = whole_re.match(article_title)
          if m: 
            articles_list.append(m[0])
            search_match = rx.match(article_title)
            if search_match:
              print("Page: %s" % search_match.group(1))

  return sorted(articles_list)

making_data(link)
```

Comment: I'm able to follow what you're saying. So if I were to also display like 'views' I can just print("Views: %s" % search_match.group(2))? I get an Index Error, how can I obtain other parts of the JSON as well?

Comment: The group only relates to the regex match object.  You can't match a dictionary, but you can reference parts of a dictionary to match against those directly.  Views would be the exact same as in your original code since it's still a dictionary key from the `article`.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Checked the answer!